# php curl POST cookie complications

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, curl, http-post

I'm using php cURL to handle a POST request to log into a website. Is there a way to determine when the login has failed? I experimented by successfully logging in w/ the correct credentials and $ch returns true, but $ch also returns true when I use incorrect credentials. I know when the credentials are incorrect (via browser) it redirects me back to the main login page.

Any ideas?

```
     function httpPost($url, $params)

   {
       try {
           //open connection
           $ch = curl_init($url);

           //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
           // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookieFileName");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
           curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

           //execute post
           $response = curl_exec($ch);

           extract($_POST);
           echo $response;

           //close connection
           curl_close($ch);

           if (FALSE === $ch)
               throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

           // ...process $ch now
       }
       catch(Exception $e) {

           trigger_error(sprintf(
               'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
               $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
               E_USER_ERROR);

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not getting a response because I accidentally typed $curl instead of $ch.
go figure.

Thanks everyone, stepping away and come back later did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Logout things from the page after you do the login. Most of the cases a page displays Logout option or similar thing. So, it can be something like these in html source:

```
>Logout<
>Signout<
<a href="http://example.com/logout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than search for true/false in your actual curl connection, search the result for a string you know will be there if successful:

```
if (strpos($result,'Welcome') ) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but as far as I can tell only the GET request returns something I can actually interrogate. $response just has a true or false value. Is there another way for me to access the actual html response from my post request?

Comment: post should still give you the page results in $result...you may need to set a user agent, etc, if the web server is disallowing you as a spider.